# Check if Object has keys

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm

I have a Object in this format.

```
const obj = [{
  name: 'name',
  items: [{
    name: 'name 1',
    items: [
      { value: 100 },
      { value: 50 }
    ]
  }]
}]
```

Imagine that all arrays repeat several times in length and an object inside another.

How I can iterate all objects in all arrays and check if all have the property "name" and "items", if it doesn't have check if has the property "value".

I trying to make a recursion but I don't no how to check if the last "items" has a value to stop and continue to check the rest.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that has actual JavaScript. It's hard to ascertain whether  an OP (*ie **you***) knows JavaScript, or is just too lazy to try to code, or truly needs help and is willing to learn.

Comment: what? Man, if I ask is because I am not getting.....

Comment: One could ask because they haven't bothered to try and would rather ask for someone else to think and work for them. If I were to help you...where would I start? I have no idea what you already know or how you intend to approach your problem coding wise? What APIs are you using? Where's the example of a desired result? How close are you to a reasonable solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my question with:

```
   function check(objs) {
     for (let obj of objs) {
        if(!('name' in obj) &&
           !('value' in obj))
          throw new Error('invalid')
        if('name' in obj)
         check(obj.items)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Besides the fact it isn't even syntactically correct it doesn't get any of the values. Had you posted the above code in your question as per SO rules, you'd get a ton of answers including mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty to check if an object has a specific property and Array.prototype.flatMap to map the inner arrays to a single array.

```
const obj = [{
  name: 'name',
  items: [{
    name: 'name 1',
    items: [
      { value: 100 },
      { value: 50 },
      {
        name: 'name 2',
        items: [{
            value: 150
        }]
      }
    ]
  }]
}];

function getValues(arr) {  
  return arr.flatMap(entry => {
    if (entry.hasOwnProperty('name') && entry.hasOwnProperty('items')) {
      return getValues(entry.items);
    }

    return entry.value;
  });
}

console.log(getValues(obj));
```